# Sample program for RPI 3 hardware PWM?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, pwm

I am trying to use the RPI 3's **hardware** PWM pin.

Is there a simple Bash script or C program that activates and controls the PWM pin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WiringPi has written a GPIO utility for testing against the Raspberry GPIO pins. It includes PWM functionallity. Check it out on http://wiringpi.com/the-gpio-utility/

Comment: This answer is supported by https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=273886#p273886